# GRUB install failed in Ubuntu 14.10 installation

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

My Ubuntu 14.10 x64 installation exits at `grub -install /dev/sda`, it says `error: cannot open '/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi:Read-only file system`. 
My computer is Lenovo-Y430p, preinstalled Windows 8.1, I have turn off the Secure Boot and Fast Boot, using UEFI boot mode in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if your computer has a locked ESP that prevents writing outside the /EFI/Boot and /EFI/Microsoft folders. A bug has already been [reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091477) in such cases (which leads to 'read-only' errors like the one you are getting).

It would be a good idea to try the workarounds given in the [bug report page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091477).